# How to use named semaphore from child

Tags: c, linux, fork, semaphore

So basically I want to suspend a bit the child process after it's creation, just so the parent prepare some data for it in a shared memory. I'm trying to use a semaphore, as suggested here: [How to share semaphores between processes using shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359322/how-to-share-semaphores-between-processes-using-shared-memory).

**Problem nr 1**: the child can't open the semaphore.

**Problem nr 2**: strerror returns an int, but man strerror clearly says it returns an char *.

To avoid "what have you tried":

```
sem = sem_open("/semaphore", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);    

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)                                        
{   
    pid = fork();                                                               

    if (pid == 0)                                                               
    {   
        sem = sem_open("/semaphore", 0);                                        
        if (sem == SEM_FAILED)                                                  
        {   
            printf( "Error : %d\n", strerror(errno ));
            exit(0);                                                            
        }
        sem_wait(sem);   
        exit(0);                                                                
    }                                                                                                                       
}

prepare_data_for_child_processes();

for (i = 0; i < mpi_comm_world->np; i++)
    sem_post(sem);

sem_close(sem);
sem_unlink("/semaphore");
```

Comment: Is the `/` in front of the name intended?

Comment: @bash.d, yes, I found so in an example, and figured out it doesn't really matter. I changed the semaphore's name, but my problem remained.

Comment: Might it be a concurrency problem? Does `sem_open` block or fail immediately?

Comment: If `strerror()` returns `int`, it means (1) you're ignoring the compiler warnings and (2) you forgot to `#include <string.h>`

Comment: @DietrichEpp, you are right, thanks, I forgot to include <string.h>

Comment: @bash.d, sem_open from child fails immediately. It can't open the semaphore created in parent process.

Comment: The argument list in the second call to sem_open seems shorter.

Comment: @haggai_e, it is shorter because it opens an existing semaphore, while   the first call creates the semaphore.

Comment: So having corrected `strerror`, what's the open error?

Comment: @Duck, "No such file or directory"

Comment: @gg.kaspersky sorry, didn't notice it was overloaded. Regarding your issue, have you tried waiting in the main process before deleting the semaphore? Maybe it is deleted before the child gets a chance to use it.

Comment: @haggai_e, that was indeed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the children to call `sem_open()` at all — they can simply `sem_wait()` on their inherited `sem_t` handle.

You probably want to restrict the semaphore to just your "work crew".  In that case, the parent should open the semaphore exclusively (O_EXCL) with restrictive permissions, and then unlink it right away.  This will prevent honest mistakes from corrupting your semaphore's state (but won't protect against hostile programs):

```
...
sem = sem_open("/semaphore", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644, 0); /* Note O_EXCL */
sem_unlink("/semaphore");

for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  if (fork() == 0) {
    sem_wait(sem);
    /* Do some work */
    exit(0);
  }
}

prepare_data_for_child_processes();

for (i = 0; i < mpi_comm_world->np; i++)
    sem_post(sem);

sem_close(sem);
```

Now, if your implementation supports it, you should instead `sem_init(1, 0)` in shared memory.  That will give you a truly anonymous semaphore restricted just to your work crew.

(And, yes, problem #2 is a missing include.)

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the answer from commentaries:

1) Turned out it was a race condition problem: the parent process deleted the semaphore before any child could open it.

2) Missed the `#include <string.h>`.