# Reader-Writer in multiple processes C

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I have a C program that parent process create a reader thread and then forks a child process that the child creates multiple writer threads.

Writer threads insert elements into shared buffer correctly but the reader thread doesn't do anything! When I put all reader and writer threads in one process the program works correctly and the reader reads elements from the buffer! Both reader and writer use `sem_t` as semaphore and `sem_wait` and `sem_post` for manage access to buffer.

This is my program pseudo code:

```
int main()
{
initialize semaphores

create reader_thread(reader code)

fork child process(server)
}

int server()
{
create writer threads(writer code)
}
```

This is buffer structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    Req_info reqinfo[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char chunk[BUFFER_SIZE][MAX_CHUNK_SIZE];
    uint64_t chunk_size[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int Isnewfile[BUFFER_SIZE];     //1 means new file
    int Islastchunk[BUFFER_SIZE];   //1 means last chunk
    int ID[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int head;
    int tail;
    int numofelement;
#ifdef SEM_V
    sem_t full;
    sem_t empty;
    sem_t mutex;
#else
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond_read;
    pthread_cond_t cond_write;
#endif
} Buffer;

Buffer *buffer_ptr;


void writer()
{
#ifdef SEM_V
    sem_wait(&buffer_ptr->empty);
    sem_wait(&buffer_ptr->mutex);
#else
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_ptr->mutex);

    if((buffer_ptr->tail + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE == buffer_ptr->head)
    pthread_cond_wait( &buffer_ptr->cond_write, &buffer_ptr->mutex );

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_ptr->mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_ptr->mutex);
#endif

    if ((buffer_ptr->tail + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE != buffer_ptr->head)
    {

    memmove(buffer_ptr->chunk[buffer_ptr->tail], chunk, chunk_size);    //Write chunk into buffer
    buffer_ptr->chunk[buffer_ptr->tail][chunk_size] = '\0';

    buffer_ptr->chunk_size[buffer_ptr->tail] = chunk_size;          //Write chunk size into buffer

    buffer_ptr->Isnewfile[buffer_ptr->tail] = Isnewfile;

    buffer_ptr->Islastchunk[buffer_ptr->tail] = Islastchunk;

    buffer_ptr->reqinfo[buffer_ptr->tail] = reqinfo;

    buffer_ptr->ID[buffer_ptr->tail] = ID;

    buffer_ptr->tail = (buffer_ptr->tail + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;

    }
#ifdef SEM_V
    sem_post(&buffer_ptr->mutex);
    sem_post(&buffer_ptr->full);
#else

    pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_ptr->cond_write);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_ptr->mutex);
#endif
}


void reader()
{
#ifdef SEM_V
        sem_wait(&buffer_ptr->full);
#endif

        if (buffer_ptr->tail != buffer_ptr->head)
            {

        if(!first){
            gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
            first = 1;
        }

        chunksize = buffer_ptr->chunk_size[buffer_ptr->head];           //Read chunk size from buffer

        memmove(chunk, buffer_ptr->chunk[buffer_ptr->head], chunksize);     //Read chunk from buffer
        chunk[chunksize] = '\0';

        Isnewfile = buffer_ptr->Isnewfile[buffer_ptr->head];
        Islastchunk = buffer_ptr->Islastchunk[buffer_ptr->head];

        reqinfo = buffer_ptr->reqinfo[buffer_ptr->head];

        ID = buffer_ptr->ID[buffer_ptr->head];

            buffer_ptr->head = (buffer_ptr->head + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;

            }
        else{
#ifdef SEM_V
        sem_post(&buffer_ptr->empty);
#endif
        continue;
        }
#ifdef SEM_V
        sem_post(&buffer_ptr->empty);
#endif
}
```

Comment: What are you reading from/writing to? If it's just a normal C buffer, it won't work. You need to use shared memory.

Comment: How about showing at least some of the *actual* code?

Comment: @Drew McGowen, each writer thread read an image file chunk by chunk and write it into a shared buffer. The shared buffer is a structure with some arrays of fields. The reader thread reads elements from buffer and write them into one storage file.

Comment: Is it actually shared memory, though? Like @ScottHunter said, you should post *actual* code; your pseudocode doesn't describe enough.

Comment: @Drew McGowen, No it's a normal buffer not a shared memory.

Comment: There's your problem - normal buffers are not implicitly shared across `fork`.

Comment: @Drew McGowen, I tried to define the buffer as shared memory but the buffer struct size is greater than the standard shared memory size and I couldn't change the struct definition. So is there another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues here: 1) whether the `sem_t full/empty/mutex` is shared between the parent process and the child process; 2) whether the buffer is shared between the parent process and the child process.

1) Since the child process resides in a separate address space, it no longer shares the same `sem_t` with the parent process. So you need to explicitly make those semaphores to be shared. As a result, the reader and writer cannot be properly synchronized. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359322/how-to-share-semaphores-between-processes-using-shared-memory) on how to share semaphore.

2) Similarly due to the [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) mechanism, the reader thread in the parent process and the writer threads in the child process no longer share the same buffer after `fork`. So you also need to explicitly share the buffer between the parent and the child. There are [several ways](http://menehune.opt.wfu.edu/Kokua/More_SGI/007-2478-008/sgi_html/ch03.html) to do this.

In your case, since your `struct Buffer` contains both semaphores and buffer, you simply need to make it shared, which will resolve both 1) and 2).