# what is difference between semaphore and shared memory

Tags: linux, shared-memory, semaphore

1. What is difference between semaphore and a shared memory ?
2. can I use semaphores between two different processes or it must be used only in threads of a same process ?

Comment: [Semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))
[Shared Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use semaphore between two different processes

Choose a name for your semaphore

```
#define SNAME "/mysem"
```

Use sem_open with O_CREAT in the process that creates them

```
sem_t *sem = sem_open(SNAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 3); /* Initial value is 3. */
```

Open semaphores in the other processes

```
sem_t *sem = sem_open(SEM_NAME, 0); /* Open a preexisting semaphore. */
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359322/how-to-share-semaphores-between-processes-using-shared-memory)

Comment: this is answer of part 2 only the part one given in your comment check it

Answer (score 3):

The semaphore is a system for synchronization 2 or plus process to access a shared resource.

The shared memory is a system for sharing a piece of memory between 2 o plus process, on the shared memory is possible write or read data to and from a process.

For example with a semaphore is possible to manage the access to shared memory for avoid the read o write non synchronized from 2 process.

Bye