# C++ Execute one child process iteration after another process

Tags: c++, process, fork, semaphore

I want to create two child processes with some iterations in them so that iteration l in process X always executes after iteration l+1 in process Y.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


using namespace std;

sem_t mut;

int x = 2;
int main()
{
    int cpX = fork();
    sem_init(&mut, 1, 1);
    if (cpX == 0)
    {
        //child A code
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            sem_wait(&mut);
            cout << "Inside X:" << getpid() << ", " << i << '\n';
            sleep(rand() % 5);
        }
        
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int cpY = fork();
        if (cpY == 0)
        {
            //child B code
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cout << "Inside Y:" << getpid() << ", " << i << '\n';
                sleep(rand() % 5);
                sem_post(&mut);
            }
            //sem_wait(&mut);
           exit(0); 
        }
        else
        {
            //sleep(50);
            
            //wait(NULL);
            //wait(NULL);
            exit(0);
            // wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

However here, X executes once, and then Y starts executing and X never executes again. Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe because the first child process gets forked off ***before*** the semaphore is initialized?

Comment: Hi, I did that too, but it didn't help. I think the issue is that semaphores created with sem_init have to be located in a shared memory space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share semaphores between processes using shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359322/how-to-share-semaphores-between-processes-using-shared-memory)

Answer (score 0):

The parent/child during a `fork` is doing a copy so they are not referring to the same semaphore object. Hence, `mut` is not shared as what you assumed. Your snippet is near correct you just need to do minor changes to work as you expect.

Since you are using an unnamed semaphore, you need to instantiate the semaphore object in a shared area:

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>

sem_t *mut = (sem_t*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(*mut), PROT_READ |PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
sem_init(mut, 1, 1);
```

With this minor adjustments, your snippet above now works as expected as they are now referring to the same semaphore object.

Also, some tips: `sem_post` is an unblocking call, whereas `sem_wait` is a blocking call. You need to be also aware that a signal sent by `sem_post` could get lost when nobody is waiting on the semaphore during that moment.

The best reference of this kinds of things is [Unix Network Programming: Interprocess Communication by Richard Stevens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139498761)