# How to reduce CPU usage in multi-producer multi-consumer shared memory IPC?

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, semaphore

I designed a shared memory struct, to work on multi-producer multi-consumer IPC.

please see the code:

```
// shm_worker.hpp
#pragma once
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

class ShmWorker {
 public:
  ShmWorker() : is_init(false), create_new(false) {}

  virtual ~ShmWorker() {
    shmdt(m_data);
    if (create_new) shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0); 
  }

 protected:
  key_t get_keyid(const std::string & name) {
    const std::string & s = "./" + name;
    if (access(s.c_str(), F_OK) == -1) { const std::string & s1 = "touch " + s; system(s1.c_str()); }
    key_t semkey = ftok(name.c_str(), 1); 
    if (semkey == -1) { printf("shm_file:%s not existed\n", s.c_str()); exit(1); }
    return semkey;
  }

  template <typename T>
  void init(const std::string& name, int size) {
    if (is_init) { printf("this shmworker has beed inited!\n"); return; }
    m_key = get_keyid(name);
    shmid = shmget(m_key, 0, 0); 
    header_size = 3 * sizeof(std::atomic_int) + sizeof(pthread_mutex_t);
    if (shmid == -1) {
      perror("shmget err");
      printf("errno is %s\n", strerror(errno));
      if (errno == ENOENT || errno == EINVAL) {
        shmid = shmget(m_key, header_size + sizeof(T) * size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | O_EXCL);
        if (shmid == -1) {
          printf("both connet and create are failed for shm\n");
          exit(1);
        }   
        printf("creating new shm %s\n", name.c_str());
        create_new = true;
        m_data = (char*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0); 
        m_size = size;
        *reinterpret_cast<std::atomic_int*>(m_data) = m_size;
        *reinterpret_cast<std::atomic_int*>(m_data + sizeof(std::atomic_int)) = -1; 
        *reinterpret_cast<std::atomic_int*>(m_data + 2*sizeof(std::atomic_int)) = 0; //  here is record the produce postion, producer add it, consumer read it so can know where to read
        pthread_mutex_t* p = reinterpret_cast<pthread_mutex_t*>(m_data + 3*sizeof(std::atomic_int));  // the mutex is used to avoid multi-producer write at the same time.
        pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr);
        pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
        pthread_mutex_init(p, &mutexattr); 
      } else exit(1);
    } else {
      m_data = (char*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0); 
      m_size = reinterpret_cast<std::atomic_int*>(m_data)->load();
    }   
  
    if (m_data == (char*)(-1)) { perror("shmat"); exit(1); }
    is_init = true;
  }

  int m_key;
  int m_size;
  int shmid;
  char* m_data;
  bool is_init;
  size_t header_size;
  pthread_mutexattr_t mutexattr;
  bool create_new;
};
```

let me explain `ShmWorker` here:
I will create a space to be my shared memory, it has some headers, to ensure the multi-producer multi-consumer works well.

there is a `mutex`, which is used for several producer, with this, one producer write, the other waits.

there is a `atomic_int`, which records the last data position, producer add it, consumer read it, so consumer knows where to read(the previous data are discard

the init function will shared in producer and consumer, will create space if no shared memory found, otherwise will connect to the memory.

```
// shm_sender.hpp
#pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "./shm_worker.hpp"

template <typename T>
class ShmSender: public ShmWorker {
 public:
  ShmSender(const std::string& key, int size = 4096) {
    init <T> (key, size);
    mutex = reinterpret_cast<pthread_mutex_t*>(m_data + 3 * sizeof(std::atomic_int));
  }

  virtual ~ShmSender() = default;

  void Send(const T& shot) override {
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    std::atomic_int* tail = (std::atomic_int*)(m_data + 2 * sizeof(std::atomic_int));
    memcpy(m_data + header_size + tail->load() % m_size * sizeof(T), &shot, sizeof(T));
    tail->fetch_add(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
  }

 private:
  pthread_mutex_t* mutex;
};
```

`Sender` is producer, which write data to shared memory, it will add the `atomic_int` when write, and it also need `mutex` before writting.

```
// shm_recver.hpp
#pragma once
#include "./shm_worker.hpp"

template <typename T>
class ShmRecver : public ShmWorker {
 public:
  ShmRecver(const std::string & key, int size = 4096) {
    init <T> (key, size);
    auto tail = (std::atomic_int*)(m_data + 2 * sizeof(std::atomic_int));
    read_index = tail->load();
    printf("read_index is %d\n", read_index.load());
  }

  virtual ~ShmRecver() = default;

  inline void Recv(T& t) override {
    while (read_index.load() == ((std::atomic_int*)(m_data + 2 * sizeof(int)))->load());
    t = *reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data + header_size + read_index.load() % m_size * sizeof(T));
    read_index.fetch_add(1);
  }

 private:
  std::atomic<int> read_index;
};
```

`Recver` is the consumer, it only cares about where to read, so it load the `atomic_int`, and read data one by one.

these code worked well a long time for me. but i meet performance problem.

The CPU usage are high, let me write a demo main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "shm_sender.hpp"
#include "shm_recver.hpp"

ShmRecver<int> * shm1, *shm2;
void RunFirst() {
  while (true) {
    int s;
    shm1->Recv(s);
    // handle 1
  }
}

void RunSecond() {
  while (true) {
    int s;
    shm2->Recv(s);
    // handle 2
  }
}

int main() {
  shm1 = new ShmRecver<int>("shm_recv1");
  shm2 = new ShmRecver<int>("shm_recv2");
  std::thread t(RunFirst);
  RunSecond();
}
```

when i ran above code, the CPU usage is 200%, i know it because i start two thread with busy waiting.

and i do some research about other method, likes `semaphore`. `sem_post` and `sem_wait` can reduce CPU usage.

but i think it can work well in single-producer single-consumer. because producer don't know how many consumers alive, one consumer read the data, and others cant read this data.

could you help on this? how to reduce CPU usage and keep the multi-producer and multi-consumer works?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

Comment: The problem is in the `Recv` as you continuously load atomic variable until it changes. There are native semaphores that can be used for interprocess signaling (waiting and notifying) that can be used on linux. Also there are libraries for interprocess communication, like boost's library that was referred in comments.

Comment: Also, you should not have multiple receivers on the same channel. It's not helpful yet complex to properly implement for multi-processing. Just add other channels if you want multiple receivers.