active waiting in the main process C
I made this code in C that allows me to create a secondary process that does certain things. The main process has to wait until the other process is ready before starting with program execution. For the moment I made this while (check_activation_flag() == 1) that waits until the process is ready. The only problem is that it is not good because it is called active wait. How could I solve it?
    ChildPID = fork();
    if (ChildPID == 0) {
        execl("./child", "./child", NULL);
        exit(0);
    } else if (ChildPID < -1) {
        kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    atomSharedPidWriteSingle(sharedPID, getpid(), ChildPID);

    while (check_activation_flag() == 1) sleep(1);
    
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
            if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                printf("Figlio con PID %d terminato con stato %d\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
            } else {
                printf("Figlio con PID %d terminato in modo anomalo\n", pid);
            }
        }
        print_statistics();
        update_energy_consumed(energy_demand);
        setEnAvailable(-energy_demand);
        energy_available = getEnAValabe();
         printf("Total energy available: %d\n", energy_available); 
        if (energy_available < 0) kill(getpid(), SIGUSR2);
    }

this is what the child process does: when it has finished initializing the variables it needs or fetching them from shared memory, it says it is ready, I recognize that this is not the best implementation choice. But I wouldn't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me solve it?
int main(){
    signal(SIGTERM, handle_sigterm);
    int sharedPID = SharedPidInit("/my_shm");
    shared_pid_data* a = (shared_pid_data*) malloc(sizeof(shared_pid_data));
    init_ipc();
    update_activation_flag();
    while(1){
        sleep(STEP_ATTIVATORE);
        a = SharedPidRead(sharedPID);
        if(a == NULL){
            printf("Memoria condivisa fallita ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        
        srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL) ^ getpid()));
        int pos = rand() % a->dimensione; 
        
        kill(a->atomi_pid[pos], SIGUSR1);
    }
    close(sharedPIDATOMO);
    aSharedPidDelete("/my_shm");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

These are the two functions that let me know if the child processes are ready to go. It is a solution I adopted to solve the problem quickly, but I would like to be able to replace them.

void atomSharedPidWriteSingle(int shm_fd, pid_t master,pid_t alimentatore,pid_t attivatore) {
    // Mappare la memoria condivisa nello spazio degli indirizzi del processo
    lock();
    shared_pid_atom = mmap(0, sizeof(shared_pid_data), PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    if (shared_pid_atom == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(1);
    }
    shared_pid_atom->alimentatore = alimentatore;
    shared_pid_atom->attivatore = attivatore;
    shared_pid_atom->master = master;
    
    unlock();
}

void update_activation_flag() {
    lock();
    shared_data->activation_flag += 1;
    unlock();
}

int check_activation_flag() {
    int flag;
    flag = shared_data->activation_flag;
    return (flag>=shared_data->num_ChildProcesses?0:1);
}



"The only problem that doesn't work as well as it does because call wait active." -- I can't make sense of this sentence. I think I can guess what you need though, and a semaphore shared between the two processes would probably be the right tool.

I edited, I meant to say that the only problem is the active waiting

I'm just wondering why you made the child process exit with exit status 0 if the call to execl returns. Wouldn't it be better for it to exit with a non-zero exit status?

Also, when would ChildPID < -1 ever be true? fork() returns -1 on error.

with a pid worth -1 I know when fork() has failed and torm the execution of the program.

Besides pipe(), in Linux you can use eventfd(). For periodic job you can create timer descriptor with timerfd_create(). For waiting child process termination instead of polling you can create descriptor with pidfd_open(), and wait on both with epoll_wait(). You can receive for signals on signal descriptor as well. In general, you need event loop. Side note: srand() before every rand() breaks randomness and makes no sense.

One portable and simple approach is to create a pipe, then fork, and have the parent read from the pipe. The child will then write something (anything) to the pipe to signal that it is ready to go. You can then close the pipes on each end, or leave them open to use as a notification channel.

It seems that you need to communicate an information between different processes.
If POSIX compliance is OK for you, you can use a Domain Socket to get a bidirectional pipe so you can exchange messages between the processes, see e.g.:
domain socket example
Marking the socket as blocking lets you block the server process during accept() API.
So you can implement the synchronization between your processes waiting, on the server process side, for an incoming connection request on a blocking socket.
IMHO the cool thing is, you can use a file path as identifier for the socket, so you do not need a free port but just a file with read and write access for your processes.
To create a unix domain socket:
    // Create socket; bind to unique pathname
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    int fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        my_log(LOG_ERR,"%s: uds SOCKET", __func__);
        return -1;
    }

    // you can mark the socket as NON blocking
    // but you want the socket to be blocking, so we comment out the following code block
    //{
    //  int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    //  fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    //}

    // setup the socket
    struct sockaddr_un * psockaddrme = &addr;
    {
        memset(psockaddrme, 0, sizeof(*psockaddrme));
        psockaddrme->sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        {
        // def_string_pathname_of_the_socket is a string with the full path of a file with read and write access for both the processes
        // could be e.g "/tmp/mysocket.txt"
            const int n = snprintf(psockaddrme->sun_path, sizeof(psockaddrme->sun_path), "%s", def_string_pathname_of_the_socket);

            if (n < 0 || n >= (int)sizeof(psockaddrme->sun_path))
            {
                my_log(LOG_ERR,"%s: uds SPRINT me", __func__);
                return -10;
            }
        }
        // the main process is the server, the child is the client
        // they have different initializations
        if (is_server)
        {
            remove the file if already existing
            if (remove(def_string_pathname_of_the_socket) == -1 && errno != ENOENT)
            {
                my_log(LOG_ERR,"%s: REMOVE", __func__);
                return -2;
            }

            // bind!
            if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) psockaddrme, sizeof(*psockaddrme)) == -1)
            {
                my_log(LOG_ERR,"%s: BIND", __func__);
                return -3;
            }

            // and listen: then, we have to accept incoming connections
            int retlisten = listen(fd, 1);
            if (retlisten < 0)
            {
                my_log(LOG_ERR,"%s: listen %i", __func__, retlisten);
                return -10;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            // connect with the server side
            const int retconnect = connect (fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) ;
            if (retconnect < 0)
            {
                my_log(LOG_ERR,"%s: connect %i", __func__, retconnect);
                return -10;
            }
            printf("connect OK\n");
        }
    }

On the 'server" side, you have to accept incoming connections; the return value from the accept is the socket file descriptor to use with recv() and send(), while on the client side the file descriptor is already returned by the connect API:
// server side: accept incoming connections
// N.B.> if the socket has NOT been declared NONBLOCK, this call waits until an incoming connection is requested
const int cur_data_socket = accept(fd, NULL, NULL);

Then, using the send() and recv() APIs as usual, you can, if you want, exchange messages between the processes.
Please note that if you do not change the socket blocking property, the recv() call blocks the calling process.
N.B.: in the following code, socket_fd is either cur_data_socket (server side) or fd (client side)
    // send a packet
    const int nsent = send(socket_fd, packet, packet_len, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
    if (nsent != packet_len)
    {
        my_log(LOG_WARNING,"%s: unable to send", __func__);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
      // OK
    }


    const int numBytes = recv(socket_fd, resp, sizeof(resp), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
    if (numBytes > 0)
    {
        // received OK
    }

If you can't use the sockets, then maybe you can use a POSIX semaphore, as other have suggested; in the following an example
// credits to:
//    https://www.softprayog.in/programming/posix-semaphores
//    https://stackoverflow.com/a/8359403/25547638

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SEM_IPC_NAME "/sem_ipc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sem_t *sem_ipc;

    printf("original is creating the ipc semaphore with an initial value of 0\n");
    if ((sem_ipc = sem_open (SEM_IPC_NAME, O_CREAT, 0666, 0)) == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        perror ("parent sem_open");
        exit (1);
    }

    printf("original is forking to create a child process inheriting the ipc semaphore\n");
    int ChildPID = fork();
    if (ChildPID == 0)
    {

        printf("child is alive and kicking!\n");
        printf("child is posting the ipc semaphore to unlock the parent\n");
        if (sem_post(sem_ipc) < 0)
        {
            perror ("child sem_post");
            exit (1);

        }
        printf("child has successfully signaled the ipc semaphore\n");
        printf("child is doing its stuff...\n");
        usleep(10);
        printf("child bye\n");

        exit(0);

    } else if (ChildPID < -1)
    {
        perror ("child pid");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // wait child process
    printf("parent is locked waiting for the child post on the ipc semaphore\n");
    if (sem_wait(sem_ipc) < 0)
    {
        perror ("parent sem_wait");
        exit (1);

    }

    printf("parent has been unlocked by child\n");

    printf("parent is doing its stuff...\n");
    usleep(10);

    if (sem_close(sem_ipc) < 0)
    {
        perror ("parent sem_close");
        exit (1);

    }

    printf("parent bye\n");

    exit(0);


}


unfortunately I am not allowed to use sockets, I should opt for something like semaphores to synchronize child processes

If you're just looking for a semaphore, sem_init is probably what you want. However, unlike a pipe, you can't use it to convey status information (e.g. whether the child process started up successfully).

Aren't sockets too overhead for parent/child process communication? Descriptor inheritance is much simpler.

@MiusiZ Since you already have memory shared between processes, you can use shared semaphore (or mutex / condition variable) in that memory.

I would like to be able to use a shared semaphore but I don't know how to use it or how to structure it

@MiusiZ Then we need to know what are those atomSharedPidWriteSingle(), check_activation_flag(), update_activation_flag() and other details. In general, shared semaphore is the same as non-shared semaphore but located in shared memory and initialized with "shared" flag.

I added the two functions that are called

@MiusiZ I added in the original post an example using a POSIX semaphore
